# How to instantiate Class object with varying number of property values

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, structure

Been working a lot with custom classes lately and I love the power you can have with them but I have come across something that I'm not able to solve and/or find anything helpful online.

I have a list of a class with properties I'm looking to only store information pulled from a database into.

```
Public Class CustomClass

        Public _Values As String
        Public _Variables As String


        Public ReadOnly Property Values() As String
            Get
                Return _Values
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Variables() As String
            Get
                Return _Variables
            End Get
        End Property

        Sub New(ByVal values As String, ByVal variables As String)
            _Values = values
            _Variables = variables
        End Sub
End Class
```

I will be iterating through some database entries, and I'm looking to store them into the appropriate property when I hit them (since I won't have them all available immediately, which is part of my problem).  I want to just be able to add either the value or the variable at a time and not both of them, but since I have the sub procedure 'New' passing two arguments, it will always require passing them both.  I've found the only way around this is by making them optional fields which I don't feel is the right way to solve this.  Is what I'm looking to do possible with a class or would it be simpler by using a structure?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. If you don't get enough information to construct the object, then defer creation of the object. Store the property in local variable(or a field), then as soon as you get both of them construct a new object. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: My original plan was to get the table entries, which are separated by commas(','), and split them into a list then iterate through and add them to this list of properties, causing me not to be able to add them seperately unless, like you said, holding them in a temporary variable.  If I was to go that route, I would have to create multiple 'holding' variables which isn't a huge deal but I just figured if I could get this handled from just the variable that held the split values, it would help with readability

Comment: Just a comment:  Your fields should be private.  (e. g. `Private _Values As String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the constructor:

```
Friend Class Foo
    ' using auto-implement props:
    Public Property Name As String      ' creates a _Name backing field
    Public Property Value as Integer

    Public Sub New(newN as String, newV as Integer)
        ' access "hidden" backing fields if you want:
        _Name = newN
        _Value = newV
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()            ' simple ctor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(justName As String)
        ' via the prop
        Name = justName
    End Sub
End Class
```

You now have 3 ways to create the object: with full initialization, partial (name only) or as a blank object.  You will often need a "simple constructor" - one with no params - for other purposes: serializers, Collection editors and the like will have no idea how to use the parameterized constructors and will require a simple one.

If rules in the App were that there was no reason for a MyFoo to ever exist unless both `Name` and `Value` being defined, implementing only the `New(String, Integer)` ctor enforces that rule. That is, it is first about the app rules, then about coding convenience.

```
Dim myFoo As New Foo         ' empty one
myFoo.Name = "ziggy"         ' we only know part of it
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the default of string is nothing, you could pass nothing for the value you don't have. IE

```
Collection.Add(New CustomClass("My Value",Nothing))
```

Every type has a default, so this works with more than just strings.